# Need to know if we can link two excel files together where the cell location changes each month

Tags: microsoft-excel

Trying to link two excel worksheets together to pull the select data from one to the other.  Issue is the row remains the same but each month the column would change and would like to be able to just change the reference each month with out doing afind and replace which takes a long time.

Comment: This question is way too broad and is likely to be closed for that reason. [This may be useful](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Well, since it's going to be closed, I'll just drop a quick strategy for you in situations like this one. No chance for waiting on details eh?

Your issue is how to specify a changing column in your formula/s. Well, there's a function called `OFFSET()` that can do just that because it allows you to specify values for rows and columns with simple numbers which can by hard coded in or specified by formulas. So you need a formula that will give you the column as the months change. No problem.

Every month has a number from 1-12 we associate with it and every month can have a year associated with it. So June 2019 would have 19 and 6 associated with it while July 2019 would have 19 and 7. If you relate the years to a base year, the difference would give you a value to multiply by 12 and add to the month number for a unique value for each month you could ever need. Your first column would be column number "something" so if you have a base year of 2012 and a "now month" of 2019, that's 7 years (*12) plus 7 for July to give you 91 for July 2019. If the first column is column L, that's column 12, and adding 91 gives you 103 for July 2019's column. `OFFSET()` takes the 103 and passes the right column to your formula.

So. Done. `OFFSET()` requires the other spreadsheet to be open when you are working. Doesn't seem like that should be an issue though from the info provided.

That kind of tool is present in a variety of Excel functions. You just have to think of some of the bits and facts that will let you feed them to get what you need. Think of things that wander about hand in hand for you:  in this case, every month the "value" of the month goes up by one AND every month the number assigned by Excel to the column being used... goes up by one. Then see how to feed a function like `OFFSET()` by adding or subtracting a base (Properly? Well, an "offset"... but I'd hate to confuse the issue!). You can even get clever and have the column value rise while the row value falls, stuff like that. The world is yours to use.